How to move multiple files from one directory to others in R?
I have a dataset where first column is a file name (in the working directory) and the second column is the directory to which I want the file to go. The dataset data2 looks like this:
     [,1]                            [,2]        
[1,] "Folder1/subfolder2/subfolder3" "File.Name1"
[2,] "Folder2/subfolder4/subfolder5" "File.Name2"
[3,] "Folder3/subfolder6/subfolder7" "File.Name3"

I tried to use the function file.copy as follows:
file.copy(from=data2[,2], to=data2[,1], 
          overwrite = TRUE, recursive = FALSE, 
          copy.mode = TRUE)

For which I get the warnings: cannot create file "Folder1/subfolder2/subfolder3", , reason 'No such file or directory'. But there is such a directory. So, I have no idea what could be the problem.

Ensure that the current working directory is what you think it is.  getwd() will display it and setwd can be used to change it.

The "to" argument of file.copy needs to include the file name, otherwise your code tries to create a file "subfolder3." in subfolder2.  Assuming you want to keep the file names the same, the following should work:
file.copy(from=data2[,2], to=file.path(data2[,1], data2[,2]), 
      overwrite = TRUE, recursive = FALSE, 
      copy.mode = TRUE)


That's what I thought, but it still doesn't work. It doesn't output any error, but there are no files in the indicated folders.

@Knaciedoo This function for some reason outputs large logical vector containing "FALSE" (it is as long as nrow of data2).

It worked, thank you!

Since you have multiple files for multiple destinations, you can use Map + file.copy
invisible(
  Map(file.copy, from = data2[,2], to = data[,1], overwrite = TRUE)
)


It doesn't work. The files are not in the corresponding directories.
